# Override python function in odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

I make some changes in the **read_group** function which is located in the **odoo/server/openerp/models**.

What I need now is to override this function in my own module. So I copy this function in the **.py** file of my module but this doesn't work for me. Can any one tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find the example as below

```
from openerp import models
def read_group():
    #YOUR OVERRIDDEN Function

models.BaseModel.read_group = read_group
```

For New API and old API compatibility issue you can also use `_register_hook` as given in example on this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34854721/1451220

Comment: from openerp.models import BaseModel
def my_user_has_groups(self, cr, uid, groups, context=None):
    #my code

BaseModel.user_has_groups = my_user_has_groups But it says TypeError: my_user_has_groups() takes at least 4 arguments (2 given)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725611/how-to-override-method-of-basemodel-openerp-models-py-in-odoo-v9

Comment: This is just an example . you have to keep signature as same as it is in core