# How to inherit Mail.Thread AbstractModel and override function from this class in Odoo?

Tags: python, abstract-class, odoo-8, overriding

I would like to change something from mail.thread abstract class. So I inherited mail.thread and wrote override message_tracked function. But it did not call override function... just only called base function. Is it cause by mail.thread is Abstract Model?

I tried like that osv.osv and osv.AbstractModel and import this py file in **init**.py and put 'mail' module in depend dic of **openerp**.py

```
class mail_thread(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'mail.thread'  

class mail_thread(osv.AbstractModel):
    _inherit = 'mail.thread'
```

they did not call any function in this class **def write** or **def message_track**

If you do not mind, please explain me how to write override function for message_track.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably related to the issue described here: 
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/9084

As a workaround you may try to solve this as described here: 
[Override python function in odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430624/override-python-function-in-odoo)

I did it like this:

```
from openerp.addons.mail.mail_thread import mail_thread

message_new_orig = mail_thread.message_new

def message_new(self, cr, uid, msg_dict, custom_values=None, context=None):
    # call super function
    msg_id = message_new_orig(self, cr, uid, msg_dict,
                              custom_values=custom_values, context=context)
    # put custom code here
    # ...

    return msg_id

# install overide
mail_thread.message_new = message_new
```

Comment: I am using odoo 9 and I have this error: from openerp.addons.mail.mail_thread import mail_thread
ImportError: No module named mail_thread