# Odoo: Method in custom module not overriding original method

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, overriding

I created a custom module that overrides the message_new method of the mail.thread model to allow creation of quotations from incoming emails by setting the values of the required fields "partner_id" etc. based on the content of the incoming email. Everything worked correctly with my method being called instead of the original one as expected.

I'm trying to move that code into another custom module now, I placed the python file within the custom module folder, added the import to the *init*.py file of the custom module and added "mail" to the depends sections of the *openerp*.py file like I did before.

But now with the new custom module installed the message_new method isn't being overridden and it's calling the original method from mail.thread. This custom module is inheriting the sale.order and sale.order.line models and the changes it's making to those models are being executed so I have no idea why mail.thread isn't being affected when the only difference between this new custom module and the old one is that the enw module is inheriting and applying changes to several models at once rather than to only the mail.thread model.

Has anyone experienced problems inheriting a model and overriding it's methods like this before?

**Update:**

Based on the answer to this question I guess it's a bug:

[How to inherit Mail.Thread AbstractModel and override function from this class in Odoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936122/how-to-inherit-mail-thread-abstractmodel-and-override-function-from-this-class-i?rq=1)

The workaround in that question didn't work exactly for me, but removing the message_new_orig declaration and subsequent call like so did:

```
from openerp.addons.mail.mail_thread import mail_thread

def message_new(self, cr, uid, msg_dict, custom_values=None, context=None):

    # put custom code here
    # ...

    return res_id

# install overide
mail_thread.message_new = message_new
```

Comment: You should add your update as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I am using odoo 9 and using your code I have this error: 
from openerp.addons.mail.mail_thread import mail_thread ImportError: No module named mail_thread