# How to override method of BaseModel (openerp/models.py) in odoo v9?

Tags: function, python-2.7, orm, overriding, odoo-9

I want to override a function called 'user_has_groups'  in the class from the file openerp/models.py  (line no 1365)

I tried the code from [this post](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-override-method-of-basemodel-orm-in-odoo-v8-61799) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430624/override-python-function-in-odoo)

```
from openerp.models import BaseModel
def my_user_has_groups(self, cr, uid, groups, context=None):
    #my code

BaseModel.user_has_groups = my_user_has_groups
```

But it results the following error.

```
TypeError: my_user_has_groups() takes at least 4 arguments (2 given)
```

and also i tried this line

```
BaseModel.user_has_groups = lambda cr, uid, groups, context: my_user_has_groups(cr, uid, groups, context)
```

It results the following error

```
QWebException: <lambda>() got multiple values for keyword argument 'groups'
```

I also tried the code from [this post](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-override-basemodel-or-model-class-of-orm-py-36517). But it doesn't work.

How I can achieve this? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this in another way around, which is given below

```
from openerp import models, api
class BaseModelExtend(models.AbstractModel):
   _name = 'basemodel.extend'

   def _register_hook(self, cr):            
      @api.cr_uid_context
      def user_has_groups(self, cr, uid, groups, context=None):
         #My code
      models.BaseModel.user_has_groups = user_has_groups
      return super(BaseModelExtend, self)._register_hook(cr)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from openerp.models import BaseModel,api

@api.guess
def my_user_has_groups(self, cr, uid, groups, context=None):
    # your code

BaseModel.user_has_groups = my_user_has_groups
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer may end up in the moderation queue for being low-quality.